# How to find out if Unity Facebook SDK is in the project?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, system.reflection, facebook-unity-sdk

I have this code:

```
m_FacebookVersion =  Facebook.Unity.FacebookSdkVersion.Build;
```

To get the version of Facebook, but I run into problems when Facebook doesn't exist.
I can't find a Define to check against i.e. #if UNITY_EDITOR.

I also tried

```
Type myType = Type.GetType("Facebook.Unity.FacebookSdkVersion");
```

But myType returns null.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, I came up with this:

```
        m_FacebookVersion = "N/A";

        Type myType = Type.GetType("Facebook.Unity.FacebookSdkVersion, Assembly-CSharp");
        if(myType != null)
        {
            PropertyInfo myProp = myType.GetProperty("Build");
            if(myProp != null)
            {
                m_FacebookVersion = (string)myProp.GetValue(null, null);
            }
        }
```

Seems I needed to look in a different Assembly.